# Why can't I append lines to new file?

Tags: python-3.x, append, lines

I want to create a new file, where I append one line at a time, just like the print output of:

```
with open("file") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line[0]==">":
            i=1
            while line[i]!=" ":
                line[i]
                i+=1
                print(line[i],end='')
            print("\n")
```

My best guess is using this code:

```
with open("newfile", "a") as newfile: 
    with open("file") as file:
        for line in file:
            if line[0]==">":
                i=1
                while line[i]!=" ":
                    line[i]
                    i+=1
                    newfile.write(line[i],end='')
                newfile.write("\n")
```

But I get:

```
File "<ipython-input-40-7a0d2eb4e1ca>", line 9, in <module>
  newfile.write(line[i],end='')

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Probably one line doesn't contain a whitespace and therefore the while loop exceeds the length of the line. Have you printed out `line` to see, why this error happens? And please post full traceback of error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you haven't checked the length of the string before checking line[i]==" ".

```
while line[i] == " ":
```

with

```
while (i < len(line)) && (line[i] == " "):
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing the index i before you write the line? You should increment i after your write or you risk setting line to a value that's out of bounds.